# Most efficient way to find the second closest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an InnoDB `meetings` table with columns:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL, [...]
```

When I need to find the upcoming meeting, I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM meetings 
WHERE meetings.date >= 'todays_date_passed'
ORDER BY meetings.date ASC
LIMIT 1
```

So this works well enough to satisfy the need. However, I now need to find the second upcoming meeting and wonder what would the proper way be?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would change the `LIMIT 1` to `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`.

Note:  `OFFSET 0` means gets the first row.  So, `OFFSET 1` means get the second row.

For performance, you want an index on `meetings(date)`.